# Problem getting Bearer Token from Twitter API

Tags: authentication, twitter

I'm trying to get set up to use the Twitter API (Application-only Authentication) and am having trouble getting the bearer token so I can start making calls.  Specifically, I'm getting HTTP 403

```
{
    "code": 99,
    "message": "Unable to verify your credentials",
    "label": "authenticity_token_error"
}
```

I have the App and Dev Environment set up and have my credentials (API key and API secret key).

I am using the Talend API Tester for all of this.

I'm just not seeing the problem.  Here is the sample request from the Twitter docs and below that, my request, straight from the browser.

Twitter Example:

```
POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.twitter.com
User-Agent: My Twitter App v1.0.23
Authorization: Basic eHZ6MWV2RlM0d0VFUFRHRUZQSEJvZzpMOHFxOVBaeVJnNmllS0dFS2hab2xHQzB2SldMdzhpRUo4OERSZHlPZw==
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 29
Accept-Encoding: gzip

grant_type=client_credentials
```

My actual Request:

```
POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic ektCUTl5Q0tWRERVUVFwUDJXYzljWlpyYTowM1ZIb -- not really a key -- xhaHByMmlqWld3RkIxa1gxaXZ6cQ==
User-Agent: My App
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 29
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Host: api.twitter.com

grant_type=client_credentials
```

Outside of the Authorization and User-Agent headers, they're identical.

Because the Talend API Tester takes the username and password and does the Base 64 encoding for the Authorization header, I even took the API key, put it together wit the API secret key, with a colon delimiting them (per the Twitter docs) and did the Base 64 encoding manually and got the same value that is being sent in the Request.

I did read that if you make too many requests you can get the 403, basically timing you out, but the Request above was just made with fresh keys and 24+ hours after my last try.  If I'm timed out, I'm not sure how long it lasts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp.  I decided to try this request using Postman and somewhat shockingly, it worked the first time.  Not sure what the problem is with the Talend API Tester, but it fails miserably here.